# Prove that if a strategy is strictly dominated, then it is never a best response.

Tags: game-theory

I came across this fact "If a strategy is strictly dominated, then it is never a best response" in chapter 6 of Steven Tadelis' Game Theory An Introduction.

It is remarked as an obvious fact, but I couldn't think of why.

According to the definition of strictly dominated, this tells me the payoff of the strictly dominated strategy (pure) is less than the payoff (or expected payoff) of the dominant (pure or mixed) strategy under all possible pure strategies of the other players.

[image]

How does this lead to the strategy being not a best response to any mixed strategies of the other players?

Edit: I figured out why so.

Comment: I don't understand.  Given that there is a superior strategy, why would you stick with the bad one?

Comment: @lulu it is a bad one in the case where the other players each play a pure strategy. But the other players could have also play a mixture of pure strategies. In that case, is the strategy still a bad one?

Comment: A "dominant" strategy is one which is at least as good against *any* strategy.

Comment: @lulu I have added the definition of "strictly dominated" from the book.

Comment: The definition doesn't explain the notation.  I don't know what reference you are using.  Usually, strategy $A$ is said to dominate strategy $B$ if $A$ is always at least as successful as $B$.  Perhaps your reference means something else by the term.

Comment: A mixed strategy randomly chooses one of the "pure" strategies. But whatever strategy is randomly played, $\sigma_i$ is better that $s_i'$, so it beats the mixed strategy as well.